# Put unstructured data to Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I have a Nodejs app with Mongodb. Now I want to user Elasticsearch to replicate data from mongo to Elasticsearch. I'm using npm package "elasticsearch". For example for collection "Posts" I have like this:

```
items: [
  {
    _id: '111111111111',
    title: 'test1',
    status: true,
  },
  {
    _id: '22222222',
    title: 'test2',
    status: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: '333333333',
    title: 'test1',
    status: {published: trye},
  }
]
```

As you can see, My data is unstructured and Elasticsearch shows me error while I'm adding these items. I want a trick to turn off Elasticsearch Restriction and allow me to add these data. I can't made changes on my data its huge.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It gives you errors because your `status` field is a boolean first, a number next, and an object at the end -> mapping conflicts. If you don't want to change the data I assume you don't expect to search over the fields that show conflicts (how could you query consistently over a field that could be anything?). Then, my best recommendation is to store the conflictual fields without indexing them. That means you will see them in the documents, but you won't be able to query them or aggregate over them. To disable indexing you set their mapping type as an `Object` and set the `enabled` mapping property to false (see [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html)).

If you want to be able to query or aggregate over everything, you must do the extra effort of preprocessing your data consistently.

Comment: I added another answer including my mapping schema but still have problem mate!